# displaying a function in javascript/html

Tags: javascript

Recently began learning Javascript on CodeAcademy and throughout the tutorials they use `console.log()`. However I heard I need to use `.innerHTML` instead when I'm just printing to a document so to practice this I wrote a small array and I want to write text using `if/else` statments with it. Sorry if my code is wrong, I'm pretty new to this but can someone explain how to implement the `.innerHTML` to this code?

Thanks in advance! (left the html in to show full layout).

```js
function mylist(myArray) {
 var backPack = [
 gear = [
     'compass',
     'rope',
     'tent',
     ],
 food = [
     'granola',
     'oats',
     'fruit',
     ],
 clothes = [
     'shirt',
     'pants',
     'underwear',
     ]
 ];
  if (backPack.clothes !== 'socks') {
      document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = "don't froget your socks!";
  }else{
      document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = "All your clothes are here!";
  };
};
function check(){
   document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = mylist();
}
```

```html
<p id='display'></p>
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue you are having? Your `innerHTML` looks fine. The only problem I see is the if statement is comparing an array `backPack.clothes` to a string `socks`. You would need to check if the array contains `socks` instead

Comment: No there are several things wrong here. `backPack.clothes` is not valid syntax either: `backPack` is an `array` and `clothes` is an *element* of an array, not a *property* of it.

Comment: @VincentNguyen Well what i'm trying to do is have the final displayed text show either "dont forget your socks" or "all your clothes are here" depending on if 'socks' are in the array or not. however i cant get anything to display so along with code error i figured i was using innerHTML wrong since ive had the issue with other attempts at it as well.

Comment: @glhrmv Yeah my bad didn't see that backpack was an array...been working with too much JSON recently lol

Comment: @glhrmv thanks for pointing that out. As far as changing the "backpack.clothes" to be a valid syntax to show if it contains socks or not, how would i go about that?

Comment: @JD `backPack[2]` will return `clothes` in this instance

Answer (score 3):

`backPack` is an array in your case and there is no property like `clothes` on this object. As a result of `backPack.clothes` you get undefined.

From structure of your date you can directly access `clothes` and again, `clothes` is an array and you use `.indexOf/.find/.some` etc to check if array contains an entry like `clothes.indexOf('socks') > -1` as condition to make sure `socks` are in array of `clothes`.

Also, you don't need to do

```
 document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = mylist();
```

This would only be true if `mylist()` is returning something that you want to add as `innerHTML` of the element.

Your `mylist` function is already doing that. i-e, it is already writing the results in html of the element `display`

```js
function mylist(myArray) {
         var backPack = [
             gear = [
                 'compass',
                 'rope',
                 'tent',
                 ],
             food = [
                 'granola',
                 'oats',
                 'fruit',
                 ],
             clothes = [
                 'shirt',
                 'pants',
                 'underwear'
                 
                 ]
             ];
          if (!(clothes.indexOf('socks') > -1) ) {
              document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = "don't froget your socks!";
          }else{
              document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = "All your clothes are here!";
          };
       };
       function check(){
           document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = mylist();
       };
       
       mylist()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
   <body>
       <p id='display'></p>
 
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `backPack` array looks weird. and all the value inside initialised.

Comment: The syntax to declare that array is kind of confusing... Why are sub arrays assigned to `gear`, `food` and `clothes` variables? What is the scope of these variables, are they `var` or `let`? If OP is new to this, maybe it's better to explain/ask...

Answer (score 1):

This should help you achieve what you're looking for. Some comments follow afterward.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
   <body>
       <p id='display'></p>
     <script>
         var backPack = {
             gear: [
                 'compass',
                 'rope',
                 'tent',
                 ],
             food: [
                 'granola',
                 'oats',
                 'fruit',
                 ],
             clothes: [
                 'shirt',
                 'pants',
                 'underwear',
                 ]
         };

          if (!backPack.clothes.includes('socks')) {
              document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = "don't froget your socks!";
          } else {
              document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = "All your clothes are here!";
          };
     </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

I removed your `mylist` function as it wasn't being called anywhere, so it would never run without you manually calling it at the bottom of your `script`. If you want to keep the `mylist` function, I'd advise you to define `backPack` **outside** of it, and pass it as a parameter.

I changed your `backPack` variable to be an [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) instead. This makes more logical sense as a backpack is an object with several spaces (collections/lists) in it. Keeping it as an array is definitely possible but an added advantage of my change is that the syntax for accessing each compartment of the backpack is the very intuitive [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

Finally, I used [`Array.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to find the element you're looking for in the `gear` array (which itself is a *property* of `backPack`). This is more readable than [`Array.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), in my opinion.

Comment: I think your if-condition should be flipped :)
Not really technical, but it might be confusing for others.